# Different Uint8Array after conversion

Tags: javascript, arrays, encoding, decoding, arraybuffer

I'm trying some stuff with the new WebCrypto API. The *window.crypto.subtle.encrypt* function outputs the encrypted text as ArrayBuffer - but later on I want to send this output to my server, so I need it as a string.
But now I'm facing some crazy problem regarding the conversion:

```
console.log(encrypted); //ArrayBuffer { byteLength: 28 } (sample output from encryption function)
var encryptedAsUint8 = new Uint8Array(encrypted);
console.log(encryptedAsUint8); //Uint8Array [ 25, 235, 161, 121, 221, 61, 132, 15, 161, 17...

var decoded = new TextDecoder("utf-8").decode(encrypted);
console.log(decoded); //�y�=��ͨ˫~���@��UcQ�
var decoded64 = btoa(encodeURIComponent(decoded));
console.log(decoded64); //JTE5JUVGJUJGJUJEeSVFRiVCRiVCRCUzRCVFRiVCRiVCRCUwRiVFRiVCRiVCRCUxMSVDRCVBOCVDQiVBQn4lRUYlQkYlQkQlRUYlQkYlQkQlMDIlN0YlRUYlQkYlQkQlNDAlRUYlQkYlQkQlRUYlQkYlQkRVY1ElRUYlQkYlQkQ=
var encodedAgain = decodeURIComponent(atob(decoded64));
console.log(encodedAgain); //�y�=��ͨ˫~���@��UcQ�
console.log(decoded === encodedAgain); //true - AS YOU CAN SEE, UNTIL THIS POINT THE CONTENT SEEMS TO BE THE SAME - but now:


var backToUint8 = new Uint8Array(new TextEncoder("utf-8").encode(encodedAgain));
console.log(backToUint8 === encrypted); //false ??????? 
console.log(backToUint8); //Uint8Array [ 25, 239, 191, 189, 121, 239, 191, 189, 61, 239,... ---> WHY IS THE ARRAY NOW A DIFFERENT ONE?
```

Thanks for any helpful advice in advance! Sorry for my bad English.

Comment: For starters `===` checks if it is *the same array* (not just an array holding the same values), which it obviously isn't since backToUint8 has been instantiated using `new`. For example `[] === []; //false, these are two separate instances of an empty Array`

Comment: Ok, and how can I create a idential array then (from the base64-encoded string, not the original array)?
Btw `[] == []` also outputs as false

Comment: Also, as you can see, the second array, precisely, is NOT holding he same values!

Comment: Thx for absolutely no answer.